# How to implement a class with FIX types

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, quickfix

Here is a working code

```
#include "quickfix/FixFields.h"
#include "quickfix/Values.h"

int main()
{
  FIX::BeginString beginString(FIX::BeginString_FIX42);
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and if I print the value of beginString I get the expected result.

Now I want to implement a class with the same type

```
#include "quickfix/FixFields.h"
#include "quickfix/Values.h"

class A {
  FIX::BeginString beginString;
public:
  A()
  {
    beginString = FIX::BeginString_FIX42;
  }
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile, the compilation error is

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
test.cpp:9:17: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘FIX::BeginString’ and ‘const char [8]’)
     beginString = FIX::BeginString_FIX42;
                 ^
```

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is that `FIX::BeginString_FIX42` is not a type. In the first code sample, you are instantiating something, in the class you are declaring a function.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but I'm 99% sure you are doing it wrong.  So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to define a class with a data member of type `FIX::BeginString`. I don't understand why the compiler is willing to assign the correct value to a variable in `main()` but won't  compile the code that tries to do the same when the variable is a data member of a class.

Comment: To initialise the member, why not use the constructor's initialiser list? That works if (as here) there's a conversion constuctor but no assignment operator.

Comment: Not only your comment is useful, it is in fact the answer to my problem. I updated my answer and give you all the credit.

Comment: Did you look at the sample code provided with the `QuickFix` library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mike Seymour using the initializer list of the constructor can be used when conversion operator exists but assignment doesn't.

```
#include "quickfix/FixFields.h"
#include "quickfix/Values.h"

class A {
  FIX::BeginString beginString{FIX::BeginString_FIX42};
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FIX::BeginString_FIX42 is a const i'm guessing.  When you define a function which again I am guessing you want to do you need to specify a type of a value not a value.  BeginString is a type BeginString_FIX42 is a constant that tells begin string which version of the begin to return.

Comment: I don't want to define a function, I want to define a member. What I don't understand is why it was so easy when I was not using `class A` but when I put it inside a class I can't compile this code and everything I tried doesn't seem to work